# Mysql with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

Here is my code that I'm using.

**ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "process.php",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
        $(".content").html(data);
    }
});

$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "post.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data1){
            $(".content").html(data1);
        }
    });
});
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","webcap");
$query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM test");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $row['num'];
}
```

**post.php**

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","webcap");
$num_query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM test");
$num_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($num_query);
$number = $num_row['num'];

$new_number = $number + 1;
$query2 = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE test SET num='$new_number'");
echo $new_number;
```

The idea is when i click button it add plus one to my database and i can see it without refreshing but others don't.

I want that everyone in my website see it in real time without refreshing

Comment: so what error you are facing ?

Comment: You will need JS on everyones computer sending AJAX requests to see if the number has been updated. If `test` has multiple rows you better use a `where` clause on that `update`. Probable better approach `SET num= num +1`.

Comment: the update query code is rather pointless. if you're just incrementing, why not just do `update test set num=num+1` as a single query? doing two queries like that opens you up to race conditions and missing increments because one script stomped on another's update.

Comment: Nice status report; thanks for sharing. Was there a *question* in there  somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ajax is only called in the javascript once, it won't update without refreshing. You need to put the ajax into setInterval and pick a refresh rate (ms):

```
Interval = setInterval(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "process.php",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
        $(".content").html(data);
    }
});
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Web pages are static unless making another request to the server for data. The only way to make repeated requests is through polling with an interval loop or setting up a push server.

Comment: Aha missed the first call OP had.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what i need @Shadouts